# how to fill values in empty rows with condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to put values in empty/NaN with condition wrt existing table
Please find the attached

**Existing Data**

```
import pandas as pd

col_names =  ['Date', 'ID', 'Individual','Category','Age','DW','Gender']

my_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)


my_df['Date']=2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,
               3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,'...',8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,
               8112019,8112019,8112019]
my_df['ID']=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,'...',1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]
my_df['Individual']=[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,'...',1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
my_df['Category']=['DE','DE','DE','C','C','C','C','A','A','A','DE','DE','DE','C','C','C','C','A','A','A','...','DE',
                   'DE','DE','C','C','C','C','A','A','A']
my_df['Age']=['51-60','02-14','31-40','02-14','31-40','15-21','22-30','60+','22-30','02-14','51-60','02-14','31-40',
              '02-14','31-40','15-21','22-30','60+','22-30','02-14','...','51-60','02-14','31-40','02-14','31-40',
              '15-21','22-30','60+','22-30','02-14']
my_df['DW']=[6554,7875,10063,5661,7851,10063,6552,2365,8569,7875,6554,7875,10063,5661,7875,'...',
             6554,7875,10063,5661,7851,10063,6552,2365,8569,7875,6554,7875,10063,5661,7875]
my_df['Gender']=['M','F','F','M','M','F','M','F','F','M','M','F','F','M','M','F','M','F','F','M',
                 '...','M','F','F','M','M','F','M','F','F','M']
```

**O/p**

```
       Date    ID   Individual  Category    Age     DW    Gender
  0  2112019    1          1    DE         51-60    6554      M
  1  2112019    1          2    DE         02-14    7875      F
  2 2112019     1          3    DE         31-40    10063     F
  3  2112019    2          1    C          02-14    5661      M
  4  2112019    2          2    C          31-40    7851      M
  5  2112019    2          3    C          15-21    10063     F
  6  2112019    2          4    C          22-30    6552      M
  7  2112019    3          1    A            60+    2365      F
  8  2112019    3          2    A          22-30    8569      F
  9  2112019    3          3    A          02-14    7875      M
 10  3112019    1          1    DE         51-60    6554      M
 11  3112019    1          2    DE         02-14    7875      F
 12  3112019    1          3    DE         31-40    10063     F
 13  3112019    2          1    C          02-14    5661      M
 14  3112019    2          2    C          31-40    7875      M
 15  3112019    2          3    C          15-21    10063     F
 16  3112019    2          4    C          22-30    5661      M
 17  3112019    3          1    A          60+      2365      F
 18  3112019    3          2    A          22-30    8569      F
 19  3112019    3          3    A          02-14    7875      M
 20  ...       ...        ...  ...           ...    ...      ...
 21  8112019    1         1    DE          51-60    6554      M
 22  8112019    1         2    DE          02-14    7875      F
 23  8112019    1         3    DE          31-40    10063     F
 24  8112019    2         1     C          02-14    5661      M
 25  8112019    2         2     C          31-40    7851      M
 26  8112019    2         3     C          15-21    10063     F
 27  8112019    2         4     C          22-30    6552      M   
 28  8112019    3         1     A          60+      2365      F
 29  8112019    3         2     A          22-30    8569      F
 30  8112019    3         3     A          02-14    7875      M
```

**I want to generate below table using condition on different combination from the above table:**

```
col =  ['Target', 'Day1', 'Day2','Day3','Day4','Day5','Day6','Day7']
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col)
new_df['Target']=['A-Category & Age 22+','F-Female & ABC-Category & Age <21','M & Age 22-30','...']
new_df
    Target                              Day1    Day2    Day3    Day4    Day5    Day6    Day7
0   A-Category & Age 22+                NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
1   F-Female & ABC-Category & Age <21   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
2   M & Age 22-30                       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
3   ...                                 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
```

I want to put agggregate sum of WT on each day based on date and different  condition on Target variable eg. in Column Table.

Comment: What is 'aggregate sum of WT'? Is it sum the `individual` column for the condition? Or count of unique values of `individual` column? Or something else?

Comment: Sum of DW for each day of the date

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a WT column, so we don't now what that is. However for this example I'll use the DW column as the aggregation column.  You can change it to suit your needs.

```
import pandas as pd

col_names =  ['Date', 'ID', 'Individual','Category','Age','DW','Gender']

my_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)


my_df['Date']=[2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,2112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,
               3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,3112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,8112019,
               8112019,8112019,8112019]
my_df['ID']=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]
my_df['Individual']=[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
my_df['Category']=['DE','DE','DE','C','C','C','C','A','A','A','DE','DE','DE','C','C','C','C','A','A','A','DE',
                   'DE','DE','C','C','C','C','A','A','A']
my_df['Age']=['51-60','02-14','31-40','02-14','31-40','15-21','22-30','60+','22-30','02-14','51-60','02-14','31-40',
              '02-14','31-40','15-21','22-30','60+','22-30','02-14','51-60','02-14','31-40','02-14','31-40',
              '15-21','22-30','60+','22-30','02-14']
my_df['DW']=[6554,7875,10063,5661,7851,10063,6552,2365,8569,7875,6554,7875,10063,5661,7875,
             6554,7875,10063,5661,7851,10063,6552,2365,8569,7875,6554,7875,10063,5661,7875]
my_df['Gender']=['M','F','F','M','M','F','M','F','F','M','M','F','F','M','M','F','M','F','F','M',
                'M','F','F','M','M','F','M','F','F','M']

col =  ['Target', 'Day1', 'Day2','Day3','Day4','Day5','Day6','Day7']
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col)
new_df['Target']=['A-Category & Age 22+','F-Female & ABC-Category & Age <21','M & Age 22-30','...']
```

Create a list of dictionaries containing all of your matching criteria.  I have skipped the second example in your list due to there not being any ABC category in your data.  If you mean any of the three, you'll have to modify this somewhat.

```
condition_list = []
groups = [
    {
      'ID':'any',
      'Individual':'any',
      'Category':'A',
      'age_min':22,
      'age_max':100,
      'Gender':'any',
      'Target':'A-Category & Age 22+'
    },
    {
      'ID':'any',
      'Individual':'any',
      'Category':'any',
      'age_min':22,
      'age_max':30,
      'Gender':'M',
      'Target':'M & Age 22-30'
    }
         ]

for group in groups:
    temp_list = []
    for key, value in group.items():
        if value == 'any':
            temp_list.append([x for x in my_df[key].unique()])
        else:
            temp_list.append([value])
    condition_list.append(temp_list)
```

Iterate over your list of conditions, slicing the dataframe, grouping, summing the aggregate column, pivoting, and appending to a final dataframe.

```
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Target'])
for condition in condition_list:
    t = my_df[
          (my_df['ID'].isin(condition[0])) &
          (my_df['Individual'].isin(condition[1])) &
          (my_df['Category'].isin(condition[2]) & 
          (my_df['Age'].apply(lambda x: int(min(x.replace('+','').split('-')))) >= condition[3][0]) & 
          (my_df['Age'].apply(lambda x: int(max(x.replace('+','').split('-')))) <= condition[4][0]) &
          (my_df['Gender']).isin(condition[5]))

    ]

    t['Target'] = condition[6][0]

    output = output.append(t.groupby(['Target','Date'])['DW'].sum().reset_index().pivot(index='Target',columns='Date',values='DW'))
```

Assign target column

```
output['Target'] = output.index
output = output.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
    2112019 3112019 8112019 Target
0   10934.0 15724.0 15724.0 A-Category & Age 22+
1   6552.0  7875.0  7875.0  M & Age 22-30
```

Comment: I want to keep the Column names day1, day2,day3 as it is and assign sum of DW

Comment: I tried running the above code in python 3.5 version :
getting the following error
TypeError    
----> 7           (my_df['Age'].apply(lambda x: int(max(x.replace('+','').split('-')))) <= condition[4][0]) &
      8           (my_df['Gender']).isin(condition[5]))
      

TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: The condition list index is getting shuffled in python 3.5 that's why getting the above error. Is there any solution to keep condition_list index constant?

Comment: Ur solution does not answers to output['Target'] index 1 i.e for Category ABC all together ----> F-Female & ABC-Category & Age <21
@Chris